# Как в Java преобразовать Date в Long, если Date до 1970 года?

Tags: java, дата

Как в Java преобразовать Date в Long, если Date до 1970 года?

Например если значение объекта date типа Date равно
Wed Jan 31 00:00:00 CET 1900

то 
Long result = date.getTime(); 
возвращает отрицательный результат: -2206400400000

Как тут быть?

Comment: Чем не устраивает отрицательный результат?

Answer (score 2):

А отрицательное значение не можеть быть long что ли?

long может принимать значения от -9223372036854775808L до 9223372036854775807L.
Число, которое Вы привели в примере(-2206400400000), входит в данный промежуток.

Если Вы имели в виду что-то другое, то переформулируйте вопрос.